# How to set custom parameter on dojox/grid/DataGrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

On a dialog, I have created a `dojox/grid/DataGrid` for displaying some data and it is working. On the selection of a row I have to populate some values on the main screen. Can I set some custom parameters on the row which will tell whether to prefill the value or not. Below is the layout, I have added a parameter - `preFillToMainScreen : true`

```
var layout = {
    cells: [
        {   
            'name': 'Reinsurance Type',
            'field': 'ReinsuranceType',
            'width': '150px'
        }, {
            'name': 'Treaty Type',
            'field': 'TreatyType',
            'width': '100px'
        }, {
            'name': 'VTGBEZ',
            'field': 'VTGBEZ',
            'width': '120px'
        }, {
            'name': 'VTGNR',
            'field': 'VTGNR',
            'width': '120px',
            'preFillToMainScreen': true
        }
    ]
};
```

How can I get the value of this parameter `preFillToMainScreen`  (either true or false) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no such functionality in that component.. Layout is locked to the three parameters your other columns are specified with - consider the following html and understand how the `layout` variable 'translates' into that:

```
     <th field="ReinsuranceType" width="150px">Reinsurance Type</th>
     <th field="TreatyType" width="100px">Treaty Type</th>
     <th field="VTGBEZ" width="120px">VTGBEZ</th>
     <th field="VTGNR" width="120px">VTGNR</th>
```

You would need to create a hidden cell / column. Then once the grid has rendered, loop over all your rows and look at the `item` data itself - checking to see if it has true/false for 'prefill'.

In other words, `preFillToMainScreen` does not belong in the layout unless it has its own column. You have the options of either using hidden cells (any arbitrary data can be contained in the store's items) or extend the dojox.grid to enhance it with your needs.